# Django: model object "has no attribute '_meta'" in class based view

Tags: python, django, meta, django-class-based-views

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I am working with class based views and for a test site, I followed the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) to setup the class based views.
For a project site (based on the project model below), I just want to create a quick CRUD application for the simple project model below.

**models.py**

```
class Project(models.Manager):
    name =  models.CharField(_('Name of the Project'), max_length = 100,)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from project.models import Project

class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Project

class ProjectUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Project
```

When I now load `\project\add`, which should call the `ProjectCreate` class, I get the following error:
**type object 'Project' has no attribute '_meta'**

I do not understand why. The model class normally does not require meta information. In other class based projects, I did not encounter this problem.

Thank you for your suggestions!

**Traceback**

```
Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.7.1

Traceback:
File "/Users/neurix/Development/vir_project_2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/vir_project_2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/vir_project_2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/vir_project_2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  168.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/vir_project_2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  130.         form_class = self.get_form_class()
File "/Users/neurix/Development/vir_project_2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form_class
  89.             return model_forms.modelform_factory(model)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/vir_project_2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in modelform_factory
  407.     return form_metaclass(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/vir_project_2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __new__
  206.                                       opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
File "/Users/neurix/Development/vir_project_2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in fields_for_model
  146.     opts = model._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /project/add/
Exception Value: type object 'Project' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change:

```
class Project(models.Manager)
```

to:

```
class Project(models.Model)
```

because `models.Model` is actual class you must extend to create custom models, and managers are actually used to override database operations models are involved in.

Comment: Is there some other thing missing?Since I do the same as you suggested, it does not remove the attribute error.

Comment: What module of 'models.Model' should be imported? There are many options but it seems that my custom model doesn't fit under any of them.