# type object 'Users' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, json, serialization, cassandra, django-rest-framework

i am using cassandra database and django, i want to serialize the data using Serializers from Django-rest-frame work.

## models.py

```
import uuid
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model

class Users(Model):
    read_repair_chance = 0.05 # optional - defaults to 0.1
    uid      = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    age    = columns.Integer(index=True)
    phno    = columns.Text(required=True)
    uname     = columns.Text(required=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "user_details"
```

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from user_details.models import Users

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('uid','uname','age','phno')
```

## views.py

```
from user_details.models import Users
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from user_details.serializers import UserSerializer

class UserList(APIView):
    def get(self, request , format = None):
        users = Users.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

## error

```
AttributeError at /show_details/
type object 'Users' has no attribute '_meta'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/show_details/
Django Version: 1.8.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'Users' has no attribute '_meta'
```

what changes should i make to display the data in serialize json format. i have tried the similar serializer.py file with MySQL data to display it, for that it is working fine. what i understood is when i call `Users.objects.all()` it display

```
>>> from user_details.models import Users
>>> Users.objects.all()
<cassandra.cqlengine.query.ModelQuerySet object at 0x045614F0>
>>>
```

so how to retrieve data and serialize it.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257955/django-restful-api-error-type-object-user-has-no-attribute-meta

Comment: possible duplicate of...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338091/django-model-object-has-no-attribute-meta-in-class-based-view

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Issue but after making following modification it works perfectly.

**serializers.py**

- instead of using serializers.ModelSerializer, use serializers.Serializer.

  ```
  class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      uid = serializers.UUIDField()
      age = serializers.IntegerField()
      phno = serializers.CharField()
      uname = serializers.CharField()

      def create(self, validated_data):
          return Users.objects.create(validated_data)

      def update(self, instance, validated_data):
          instance.uid = validated_data.get('uid', instance.uid)
          instance.age = validated_data.get('age', instance.age)
          instance.phno = validated_data.get('phno', instance.phno)
          instance.uname = validated_data.get('uname', instance.uname)
          instance.save()
          return instance
  ```